# How to get row from dataset with sql query?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i need to take some row. They came from sql TARIH (sql column) is smalldatetime format. But give me error  :   DataRow[] rows = dsChart.Tables[0].Select("TARIH<='" + datestart + " " + txtStartDateTime.Text + "' and TARIH>='" + dateend + " " + txtEndDateTime.Text+"'");

**Cannot perform '<=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.**

```
 dsChart = eReport.ToDataSet();
                    if (txtStartDateTime.Text != "" && txtEndDateTime.Text != "")
                        if (ValidateHoursGap(txtStartDateTime.Text.Trim()) &&
                            ValidateHoursGap(txtEndDateTime.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            DataRow[] rows = dsChart.Tables[0].Select("TARIH>='" + datestart + " " + txtStartDateTime.Text + "' and TARIH<='" + dateend + " " + txtEndDateTime.Text+"'");
                            dsChart.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();
                            dsChart.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rows);
                        }
```

Comment: What are these datestart and dateend variables ? In dataset expressions, dates must be formatted  like that : "#05/27/2009#" or "#05/27/2009 10:33:51#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's not recognizing your string as a valid datetime. The easiest way is to cast your strings to date using the appropriate SQL function.

Assuming it's SQL2005, you need to use CONVERT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx

So it would look similar to this:
TARIH>=CONVERT(smalldatetime,'" + datestart + " " + txtStartDateTime.Text + "',)

Where format is a number describing the format you're using for your your string, the link above has a list of valid formats.

Comment: He's quierying a dataset, not the server, therefore this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it isn't able to parse `datestart + " " + txtStartDateTime.Text` as a DateTime and therefore treats it as a String.

I would do this conversion before calling the `Select` method and then use `DateTime.ToString()` passing in datetime format that will work with `DateTime.Parse` (used internally by `Select`). e.g. if datestart is in the format "dd/MM/yyyy" and the input expected from `txtStartDateTime` is in format "HH:mm"

```
int hours = txtStartDateTime.Text.Substring(0,2);
int minutes = txtStartDateTime.Text.Substring(3,2);    
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(datestart.Substring(5)), Int32.Parse(datestart.Substring(3,2)), Int32.Parse(datestart.Substring(0,2)), Int32.Parse(hours), Int32.Parse(minutes));
```

Then call

```
string dateFormat = "{0:s}";  
DataRow[] rows = dsChart.Tables[0].Select(string.Format("TARIH >= '{0}' AND TARIH <= '{1}'"), dtStart.ToString(dateFormat), dtEnd.ToString(dateFormat));
```